# Properly using C# lock in web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, locking

I have a helper class which reads a big XML document and generates a list of c# objects.

I work with these objects quite a lot, so i thought the best way of doing this would be to save them in memory and then access them from there.

I made a simple repository, which gets an object from memory, and if doesn't exists, it adds it.

The Repository looks like this:

```
public class XmlDocumentRepository
{
    private readonly ICacheStorage _cacheStorage;
    public XmlDocumentRepository(ICacheStorage cacheStorage)
    {
        _cacheStorage = cacheStorage;
    }

    private readonly object _locker = new object();

    private void DeserializeXmlDocument()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            // I deserialize the xml document, i generate the c# classes, and save them in cache
            IEnumerable<Page> pages = new XmlDeserializerHelper().DeserializeXml();    

            foreach(var page in pages)
            {
                _cacheStorage.Add(page_Id, page);
            }
        }
    }

    public Page GetPage(Guid page_Id)
    {
        Page page = _cacheStorage.Get<Page>(page_Id);
        if (page != null)
            return page;

        lock (_locker)
        {
            page = _cacheStorage.Get<Page>(page_Id);
            if (page != null)
                return page;

            DeserializeXmlDocument();

            page = _cacheStorage.Get<Page>(page_Id);
            return page;
        }
    }
}
```

The `XmlDocumentRepository` is used inside a web application (asp.net mvc more exacly).

Is the implementation of the repository good? I am using the `lock` statements properly?

Comment: Why would you be multithreading in a web application?

Comment: Are `XmlDocumentRepository` and whatever the implementation of `ICacheStorage` is single instances shared across all requests on the server?

Comment: @TrevorPilley: no, normally i would create an instance of XmlDocumentRepository per web request.

Comment: @GrantThomas: I want to prevent calling the DeserializeXml() method by multiple users which tries to access an object that doesn't exist

Comment: @RaraituL is the `ICacheStorage` a singleton?

Comment: @TrevorPilley: ICacheStorage is injected by Ninject everytime i request it, but in my application, ICacheStorage is implemented by HttpContext.Current.Cache

Comment: But the `Cache` does serialization, so you're doing it twice this way.. Or maybe I don't fully comprehend what you wish to do, or even why.

Comment: XmlDocument needs extra processing when is being deserialized, so this needs to be done be a special helper class

Comment: Do you even need locking? You are caching per request so each request gets its own cache, you will never find anything in the cache unless within a single request you make multiple calls to the cache because each request results in a new context. 2 separate incoming requests will result in each getting a separate repository which will each point to a separate cache.

Comment: @TrevorPilley: I just need to prevent reading xml by multiple threads at the same time. The cacheStorage should be thread safe by itself. And, from what i know, HttpContext.Current.Cache is shared between all users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my comments on the question I misunderstood the cache being shared. I think you will need to do one of the following options:

- Make `XmlDocumentRepository` a singleton which is used across all requests because the lock object is a private field so each request will have a new instance of the repository with a new field.
- Make the lock object a static field so that it is shared across all `XmlDocumentRepository` instances.

Answer (score 0):

As a primary rule, you want to protect all access variations to data stores that are used by multiple threads. I see several potential problems with your implementation;

1: ICacheStorage is provided from the outside, which means that this collection could be modified elsewhere, which may or may not be protected by locks. Maybe you should require that the collection itself uses locking internally, or other types of thread safety mechanisms?

2: You have inconsistent lock protection of data access. In GetPage you access _cacheStorage before applying the lock, while in Deserialize, you access it inside a lock. This means that you may get a result where one is adding to the cache while another is getting from it.

3: Do you require thread safety for the cache, for xml reading, or both?
If you only need to protect the cache, move reading of xml outside the lock. If protecting both, you should put the entire GetPage function inside the lock.

Comment: I only need to prevent reading xml by multiple threads at the same time. Saying that 3 users are getting at the same time a Page which doesn't exist, only the first user (thread) should call the DeserializeXml() method while other threads waits for it. Without locking the threads, all the 3 users would call DeserializeXml() method

Comment: The simplest solution then is to wrap the entire function body in the lock so that you protect data access to your cache. Outside access is still a possibility though, so the better way would be to have a threadsafe caching collection and use the lock only to manage the xml. Trevor Pilley in the answer below addresses this.